# Novice Coder Question: How to get javascipt to identify if a date input is null?

Tags: javascript

I have written a basic JavaScript code to alert user of a form that the start date input (x)  cannot be less than the end date input (y) which works perfectly. Currently, when the values are null I get the same alert. What I would like is that when the values are null that form can be processed without an alert. I'm a novice coder can someone help me out?

```js
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["n"]["d5","d7", "d9", "d11", "d13", "d15", "d17", "d19","d21", "d23", "d25"].value;
    var y = document.forms["n"]["d6","d8", "d10", "d12", "d14", "d16", "d18", "d20","d22", "d24","d26" ].value;
    if ( x = null ) {
  
  return true;
}
    


 


  }
```

Comment: `!y` would make condition true if `y` is a falsy value or you could use `x === null`. `=` is for assignment and `===` is for strict equality

Comment: Thank you. I meant to remove the if statement for the x and y assignment before posting my question.  I have tried both === and == with no change. That's why I'm seeking help. Not quite sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You used an assignment operator in your conditional statement (y = null). Use == or === instead to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but it doesn't work. That's why I am seeking help. When I use === and ==  I still get the same result for the null value.